# How to render component inside a component based on route

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have routes like this:

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Route path="/"  component={App} />
        <Route path="/customers" component={Customers} />
        <Route path="/tickets" component={Tickets} />
    </BrowserRouter>
</Provider>
```

When the route is `/customers` I want `Customers` component **inside** `App` component. When the route is `/tickets` I want `Tickets` **inside** `App` and not `Customers`. I could check the route using

`this.props.location.pathname == '/customers'` but that's what the Router is for, right? I shouldn't be checking the route and rendering.

Based on my routes above, I see `Customers` component **below** `App` and not inside it.

The  `App` consists of header and stuff. I don't want to add header code to all my components.

App.js:

```
     <Header style={{ height: '39px', lineHeight: '39px' }}>
       <Link to="/home">
         <div className="logo" style={{ float: 'left' }}>
           <img src="" />
           <h2>Appnam</h2>
         </div>

       </Link>
       {navEl}
  </Header>
  <Content >
     // Customer or Tickets component here based on route
  </Content>
```

How do I render the components inside `App` based on the route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have App as the main component, and you want the Tickets and Customers components inside the App component, you can make use of nested routes

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Route path="/"  component={App} />
    </BrowserRouter>
</Provider>
```

---

Inside App component

```
class App extends React.Component {
   render() {
       return (
          <div>
             {/* rest of App code */} 
             <Route path="/customers" component={Customers} />
             <Route path="/tickets" component={Tickets} />
          </div>
       )
   }
}
```

Comment: so which ever Component I  put a <Route path="/customers" /> that component will be rendered in that parent component?

Answer (score 0):

make use of.

```
<Provider store={store}>
<BrowserRouter>
    <Route exact path="/"  component={App} />
    <Route exact path="/customers" component={Customers} />
    <Route exact path="/tickets" component={Tickets} />
</BrowserRouter>
```

that will work